# strange behaviour wired network

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, network-manager, wired, automatic

In Kubuntu 20.04, I have to put the cable of the wired network in and out for have to wire on.

Of course, I can also do `sudo nmcli networking off/ on` this will work too. I cannot find the issue of what is going on and why it doesn't get automatically. If using WiFi, I have also to fill in the `kwallet`. This is really strange.

Everything works perfectly accept the automatic online. Using commands and it works.

What could be a problem here?

Do you know it? Where are the configs of the network manager besides in the root? Is there also somewhere in the home dir?

I hope someone can give me some ideas to resolve this.

Comment: Edit your question and start by showing me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: d8:cb:8a:ed:18:4f
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.178.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df204000-df204fff memory:df200000-df203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: f4:f2:6d:c7:05:f1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.4.0-33-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:df100000-df10ffff

/etc/network/interfaces: Bestand of map bestaat niet ( don't exsist )

## This is the network config written by 'subiquity'

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

Answer (score 0):

I added interfaces

## interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

## Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:

## This file describes the network interfaces available on your system

## and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

## The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

The problem still exist. When I log in i have to start the wired interface on the network-manager. 
yesterday there was a update and I hoped there was a solution, but still I need to put on the network it is still not automatic

during the update the network-manager goes down and up again. It is only by login I need to start the network.